# Adobe AEM: Iterator returned from user.memberOf() not allowing Next() method

Tags: java, adobe, aem, jcr

pretty new to Java dev as well as adobe CQ dev and I'm a bit stumped at the moment. I am attempting to return a formatted table of all users and the groups they are associated to using the UserManager.

Everything appears to be setup and working correctly, however, I receive an error when it reaches my while loop to iterate through the Iterator returned by the Authorizable.memberOf() method. When it reaches the Next() method it returns an error stating "The method Next() is undefined for the type Iterator". Not sure what to do at this point. Any help would be appreciated. The specific code section in question is below.

```
while(paths.hasNext()) {  
Node node = paths.nextNode();
String UID = node.getProperty("jcr:uuid").getString();
String usrName = node.getProperty("rep:principalName").getString();
Authorizable usr = usrMgr.getAuthorizable(UID);
Iterator<Group> itrGrp = usr.memberOf();
String grpList = "";
while(itrGrp.hasNext()) {
    Group grp = itrGrp.Next();
    Value[] grpVal = grp.getProperty("rep:principalName");
    String[] grpArr = Arrays.copyOf(grpVal, grpVal.length, String[].class);
    int arrLen = grpArr.Length;
    If (arrLen > 1) {
        for(int i=0; i<arrLen; i++){
            grpList = grpList + grpArr[i] + "<br/>";
        }
    }else{
        grpList = grpList + grpArr[0];
    }
}
out.println("<tr><td>" + usrName + "</td><td>" +grpList + "</td></tr>");

}
```

Also, here are all my imported interfaces in case it's applicable:

```
java.util.Iterator,
javax.jcr.query.Query,
javax.jcr.NodeIterator,
javax.jcr.Node,
javax.jcr.PropertyIterator,
javax.jcr.Property,
javax.jcr.Value,
javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials,
javax.jcr.RepositoryFactory,
javax.jcr.Repository,
javax.jcr.Session, 
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.JackrabbitSession,
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.UserManager,
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Authorizable,
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Group
```

Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense or if I didn't include enough info. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to setup your project using maven and work with a proper IDE, such as eclipse or intellij idea. You will be suprised how fast you can develop code in java, they are also offering a pretty good help with the java syntax and autocompletion for java newbies. Check [this link](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html) on how to setup your aem project with maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the method `next()` instead of `Next()` (note the lower case 'n')

Comment: Oh wow....I really hate myself right now. I've been stuck on this for more than an hour. Thanks a lot. I can't believe I managed to waste this much time on a capital letter haha.

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Just a head's up for any other newbie's that are looking for answers during early mess-ups, there are quite a few additional problems with the code I posted unrelated to the issue I was asking about (which was using Next() instead of next()). I've now corrected all of the additional issues and the code is listed below. Bullet point list of additional mistakes I made:

- The UUID String property of a user account in adobe AEM is not the same as the ID property that needs to be passed to the UserManager.getAuthorizable(ID) method from the apache.jackrabbit interface.
- Attempting to use the literal property name listed for a group ("rep:principalName") in order to return the property value when utilizing the Group interface from jackrabbit is also not useful
- Bottom line, I know for sure I am incorrectly communicating information between javax.jcr and apache.jackrabbit interfaces, but do not know how to properly pass a property name existing in one interface type to the other
- However, I did figure out a crappy little work-around that utilizes the path property which can be obtained from the node interface of AEM (javax.jcr) and can be passed as a string to the jackrabbit interface method of getAuthorizableByPath(String path) to obtain the Authorizable object I was looking for.
- I am almost certain this is not the best approach but do not know the proper syntax to pass the properties between interfaces. I would definitely appreciate anyone that could post the proper way to do that :)

  ```
  while(paths.hasNext()) {  
  Node node = paths.nextNode();
  String usrPath = node.getPath();
  Authorizable usr = usrMgr.getAuthorizableByPath(usrPath);
  String usrName = node.getProperty("rep:principalName").getString();
  Iterator<Group> itrGrp = usr.memberOf();
  String grpList = "";
  if (itrGrp.hasNext()){
  while(itrGrp.hasNext()) {
      Group grp = itrGrp.next();
  String grpPath = grp.getPath();

  grpList = grpList + grpPath + "</br>";
  }
  }
  out.println("<tr><td>" + usrName + "</td><td>" +grpList + "</td></tr>");
  }
  ```